Angular Monaco editor is not working in production
I am using Angular 17 with this package ngx-monaco-editor-v2.
ngx-monaco-editor-v2: 17.0.1
monaco-editor: 0.44.0
It is working on my local machine, and I don't see any errors in the build. However, I got the error below in production.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^ {0,3}({1,6} ").replace("|lheading","").replace("|table","").replace("blockquote"," {0,3}>").replace("fences"," {0,3}(?:{3,}(?=[^\n]\n)|~{3,})[^\n]\n").replace("list"," {0,3}(?:[*+-]|1[.)]) ").replace("html","</: Nothing to repeat (at editor.main.js:25:13504)
